# How to load an image in gitlab-ci.yml when the version tag is inside a file?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to create a file `.terraform-version` with the content:

```
0.13.4
```

Then in `gitlab-ci.yml` I want to load the version for select image, like:

```yaml
variables:
   TERRAFORM_DOCKER_TAG_VERSION: $(head -n 1 .terraform-version)

# ...

PlanMRDev:
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:$TERRAFORM_DOCKER_TAG_VERSION
```

But the content of the `$TERRAFORM_DOCKER_TAG_VERSION` will be the string `$(head -n 1 .terraform-version)`.

I also tried with:

```yaml
before_script:
  - export TERRAFORM_DOCKER_TAG_VERSION=$(cat .terraform-version)
```

But in this case the `$TERRAFORM_DOCKER_TAG_VERSION` will be empty.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Gitlab Dotenv Artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#artifactsreportsdotenv). This is a feature of Gitlab that allows you to define a special kind of artifact - a file containing environment variables - that will be loaded automatically by all subsequent jobs that would normally load the artifacts (previous stages or defined with a `need` clause).

This is how the jobs would look:

```
prepare:
  script:
    - echo "export TERRAFORM_DOCKER_TAG_VERSION=$(cat .terraform-version)" >> version.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: version.env

PlanMRDev:
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:$TERRAFORM_DOCKER_TAG_VERSION
```

Comment: I made `- echo "TERRAFORM_DOCKER_TAG_VERSION =$(head -1 .terraform-version)" >> version.env` to avoid last empty line in `.terraform-version`